# Any way to append two monadic lists in Haskell?

Tags: string, list, haskell, io, monads

I am learning Haskell at Uni this semester. I encountered a problem where I have a list of lists as `IO [[String]]` and I want to append an `IO [String]` to the first one.

Lets denote them as x and y. So I tried doing `y >>= return . (++) [x]` or `y <> [x]`. All of them gave the error: `Could not match IO [[String]] with [IO [String]].` Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest general technique to learn is about how to use `do` blocks.

```
test :: IO [[String]]
test = do
   xss <- generateListOfLists  -- IO [[String]]
   xs  <- generateList         -- IO [String]
   return (xss ++ [xs])
```

The idea is that `<-` temporarily unwraps the monad, removing the `IO` monad from types, as long as at the very end we return a value in the same monad (the `return` at the end).

After one understands that general technique, one can then learn alternatives like applicative notation, which is not as general, but still nice.

```
test :: IO [[String]]
test =
   (\xss xs -> xss ++ [xs])
   <$> generateListOfLists
   <*> generateList
```

Using `>>=` is less common, and at least in this case, less convenient than a `do` block.

```
test :: IO [[String]]
test = 
   generateListOfLists >>= \xss ->
   generateList >>= \xs ->
   return (xss ++ [xs])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this in my code. Our lecturer does not want us to use `do` block because he thinks it is not purely "functional". Because of that, I am not wholly familiar with the use of `do` block.

Comment: @tugudd There is no significant difference between `do x<- ...` notation and `... >>= \x ->` notation. You can convert either of them into the other. It's only a different syntax for the same thing. If one is "not purely functional", so is the other.